# How to correct the following query?

Tags: mysql

I want to get all those tuples for which the difference of current date and SERVICE_DATE is 7.

```
SELECT count(distinct *) FROM item_serial WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), SERVICE_DATE) = '7'
```

Comment: All the tuples, or the number of them? And `SERVICE_DATE = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY` will probably be faster if `SERVICE_DATE` is indexed; using functions on field values in WHERE clauses tends to kill performance.

Comment: Just the number of tuples.

Comment: Why '7' and not  only the number 7 ?... datediff return the diff in number of day

Comment: Other than the performance-related change I previously mentioned, I do not notice anything wrong with your query (as long as `SERVICE_DATE` is a date field). _Unless you want ALL tuples and not just the unique ones; in which case, remove the `DISTINCT`._